# Mocking required modules with Sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon

I am in the process of testing a controller for my backend Express server and am struggling to stub and/or spy on a required module.

Here is an example of what my controller looks like:

```
const logger = require('../../middleware/logger');

module.exports.verify = (req, res) => {
    const log = logger(req, __filename);

    controller.verify(req.query.code, (err, response) => {
        log('Verifying query code.');
        // ...

        // error
        log.error(e, 'There was an error.');
    });
};
```

In my test, I would like to make sure that my `log` and `log.error` methods were called with the specified arguments. I have had *some* success by using [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) and stubbing the functionality, but I am not sure how to spy on it.

```
const controller = proxyquire(
    '../../middleware/logger`: sinon.stub().callsFake(() => (() => {}));
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const logger = require("./logger");
const controller = require("./controller");

module.exports.verify = (req, res) => {
  const log = logger(req, __filename);

  controller.verify(req.query.code, (err, response) => {
    log("Verifying query code.");
    log.error(err, "There was an error.");
  });
};
```

`logger.js`:

```js
module.exports = function logger(req, filename) {
  function log(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
  log.error = function error(error, message) {
    console.error(message);
  };
  return log;
};
```

`controller.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  verify(code, callback) {
    callback();
  },
};
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const controller = require("./controller");

describe("verify", () => {
  let sandbox;
  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });
  it("should verify correctly", () => {
    const logErrorStub = sandbox.stub();
    const logStub = sandbox.stub();
    logStub.error = logErrorStub;
    const loggerStub = sandbox.stub().callsFake(() => logStub);
    const { verify } = proxyquire("./", {
      "./logger": loggerStub,
    });
    const controllerVerifyStub = sandbox.stub(controller, "verify");
    const mReq = { query: { code: 123 } };
    const mRes = {};
    const mError = new Error("verify error");
    verify(mReq, mRes);
    controllerVerifyStub.yield(mError, null);
    sandbox.assert.calledWith(controllerVerifyStub, 123, sandbox.match.func);
    sandbox.assert.calledWith(loggerStub, mReq, sinon.match.string);
    sandbox.assert.calledWith(logStub, "Verifying query code.");
    sandbox.assert.calledWith(logErrorStub, mError, "There was an error.");
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 verify
    ✓ should verify correctly (57ms)


  1 passing (62ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    86.49 |      100 |       60 |    86.11 |                   |
 controller.js |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 3 |
 index.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 logger.js     |       20 |      100 |        0 |       20 |           3,5,6,8 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57808949